# How to prove that $v^TAw = w^TAv$ for symmetric $A$

Tags: linear-algebra

If I know that my matrix $\mathbf{A}$ is symmetric, how can I prove that for vectors $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{w}$, $\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{Aw}=\mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{Av}$? I have done a small example and it seems to be true, but I want to be able to formally prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick and easy way to show this is to take the tanspose of the left hand side of you equation.

Comment: But how does that prove it? To me, it just proves that one side is the transpose of the other.

Comment: Is it because the transpose of a scalar is equal to itself?

Comment: @Sandi that's exactly the point: the transpose of a scalar is equal to itself

Answer (score 1):

For practice, here's my proof:

$$
\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{Aw} = (\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{Aw})^T
$$

since a scalar is its own transpose.

Re-arranging the right hand side gives

$$
\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{Aw} = (\mathbf{Aw})^T\mathbf{v}
$$
$$
\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{Aw} = \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{v}
$$
Due to symmetry, we can write
$$
\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{Aw} = \mathbf{w}^T\mathbf{Av}
$$

And our proof is complete.